# Why my ListAdapter display items cyclically?

Tags: android

I have a ListFragment with AbsListView and I write a ListAdapter:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item, container, false);
    AbsListView mListView = (AbsListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    mListView.setAdapter(getAdapter(inflater));
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

private ListAdapter getAdapter(final LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return new ListAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_template, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
                holder.itemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
                holder.opTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_op);
                holder.itemTv.setText(list.get(position).getName());
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

When I debug it step by step, the `list` have 14 items but `getView` method was only called 7 times(7 items exactly filled my screen). When I slide the AbsListView up, `getView` was called 2 more times, and the first 5 items disappear again.

For example, my `list` have {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13}, the result is:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6(Items below here only disappear after sliding AbsListView up)
7
8
0
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I debug it step by step, the list have 14 items but getView method was only called 7 times(7 items exactly filled my screen).

The Adapter is instantiating new `View`s to fill the screen. After that, if you have only one type of `View` to display your array of objets, them Android will reuse those `View`s to optimize the process (it is expensive to create new Views for each object in your array).

After those 7 `View`s are created, then you are not updating it (you only update when the `convertView` is null, e. g. in the first 7 `getView(...)` calls.

The solution them should be:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_template, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
        holder.itemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
        holder.opTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_op);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.itemTv.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because of convertView. convertView is a view thats created and recycled through scrolling the list. this view makes GC be called less and also save memory for you. it first assigned by your earliest items of list after you scroll the list, for example item one of list disappears and you see item 15 the convertView of item one is passed again to you. in this time it is not null so you skip assignment to it and it holdes the reference of last  assignments that is the assignment of item one.

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_template, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
            holder.itemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            holder.opTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_op);
            holder.itemTv.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        }
       // here you must use holder.opTv to change values for example initialize to new one
       //  here you must use holder.itemTv to change values for example initialize to new one
      // .....

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getView` method isn't quite good. See this example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_example

It should look similar to that:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_template, null);
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
            holder.itemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            holder.opTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_op);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = convertView.getTag();
        holder.itemTv.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I modify `getView` method:

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_template, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
            holder.itemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            holder.opTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_op);
            holder.itemTv.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            return convertView;
        }
```

Just remove `if (convertView == null)` Now it works well. Who can explain it?

Comment: You are loading a new layout every time with this. `convertView` acts as a view holder so that your list doesn't have to reload all of the resources every time. What you are doing here is inefficient. You need to check if your convertView is null and if not set it, and then outside of your null check you need to actually modify your view. See any of the answers for how to implement this (you can also implement a custom ViewHolder class). The reason for it is that the findViewById call requires a bit of processing work, so avoiding calling that for every list item view helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_template, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);
            holder.itemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_name);
            holder.opTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_op);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.itemTv.setText(list.get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }
```